# Passivation of CDI SessionBean with Constructor Injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, weld

I have following CDI Bean:

```
@SessionScoped
public class ReportService implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private MyDao myDao;

    @Inject
    public ReportService(MyDao myDao) {
        this.myDao = myDao;
    }
}

@RequestScoped
public class MyDao extends AbstractDao<Order> {

    protected MyDao() {

    }

    @Inject
    public MyDao(EntityManager em) {
        super(em);
    }
}
```

If i start my webapplication (Tomcat with Weld) the following Exception is thrown:

> WELD-001435: Normal scoped bean class
>   com.myorg.ReportService is not proxyable because it
>   has no no-args constructor - Managed Bean [class
>   com.myorg.ReportService] with qualifiers [@Any
>   @Default].

How is it possible to use constructor injection in a SessionScoped Bean?
Is it safe just to add a package-visible no-args constructor?

I already searched a lot, but i did not find any information about passivating a CDI Bean whitch uses Constructor Injection.

Comment: Is `MyDao` a public class? Does it have a no-arg constructor?

Comment: Weld complains about the no-arg constructor because it wants to *proxy* your bean. This has nothing to do with passivation. CDI/EJB is responsible for passivating a bean and then restoring it to full functional state. Activation does not have to construct the object again using the constructor (I think). **Bottom line: I believe it is OK to add a package-private default constructor to your bean class.**

Comment: edited my post: added MyDao code
MyDao is a @RequestScoped CDI Bean. If i delete the protected Constructor there, then the Same Weld Error is thrown.

WELD-001435: Normal scoped bean class com.myorg.MyDao is not proxyable because it has no no-args constructor - Managed Bean [class com.myorg.MyDao] with qualifiers [@Any @Default].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is based on [CDI specification requirements](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#unproxyable), namely the need to have no-args constructor. When instantiating the object, CDI will of course prioritize a constructor annotated with `@Inject`, so don't worry about that.

The real reason why you need no-args one is for *proxies*. Weld/CDI will try to create one or more proxies of your object, which are basically an enriched delegates. In order to instantiate them, you want to invoke no-arg constructor - think of it as Java limiation, you shouldn't be instantiating objects without calling constructors. Therefore the spec mandates the need for no-arg constructor. As a matter of fact, Weld itself allows you to [bypass this need](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#relaxedConstruction) *in certain cases*, but I strongly suggest against it.

> Is it safe just to add a package-visible no-args constructor?

Yes, go ahead and do that.